# SQL COUNT(*) doesn't work in PostgreSQL but in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, group-by

I don't know why the following Query works perfect in MySQL but not in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT MAX(Anzahl) max_cnt, PID
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) Anzahl, PID, postID 
FROM PersonLikesPost
GROUP BY (postID) 
ORDER BY Anzahl DESC) as d
```

PostgreSQL says, that i need the PID in the GROUP BY clause. But then i get a other result.

Regards.

Comment: It works in MySQL because, by default, it allows to ask for incoherent results. Fix the query and it'll work in either DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

this is possible in mysql because of the following

> MySQL extends the standard SQL use of GROUP BY so that the select
>   list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY
>   clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can
>   use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary
>   column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when
>   all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are
>   the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from
>   each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are
>   indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group
>   cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting
>   occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect
>   which values within each group the server chooses.

have a look at the documentation in this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

Other DBMS may do not extend the standard SQL use of GROUP BY so the select list in other DBMS can refer only to aggregated columns

ie
in other DBMS this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Anzahl, PID, postID 
FROM PersonLikesPost
GROUP BY (postID)
```

have to be translated into this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Anzahl, PID, postID 
    FROM PersonLikesPost
    GROUP BY Anzahl, PID, postID
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This query doesn't work, too.
Now PostgreSQL says: 
Error:  Aggregated functions are not allowed in GROUP BY.